# Integer ASCII value to character in BASH using printf

Tags: bash, ascii, printf

Character to value works:

```
$ printf "%d\n" \'A
65
$
```

I have two questions, the first one is most important:

- How do I take 65 and turn it into A?
- \'A converts an ASCII character to its value using printf. Is the syntax *specific* to *printf* or is it used anywhere else in BASH? (Such small strings are hard to Google for.)

Comment: In Windows, use ALT+65 to print the ASCII character - unfortunately that won't work using Unix/bash ;)

Comment: @schnaader but you can not script that.

Comment: @richard: Errr.. it's not easy nor practical, but you could :) "Just" start a VM running Windows or MS-DOS, send "echo ", ALT, 6, 5, ">mysharedfolder\file.txt" as keystrokes to it and read file.txt from the VM shared folder.

Comment: @schnaader could you use wine to do that?

Comment: Peak shitposting

Answer (score 93):

One line

```
printf "\x$(printf %x 65)"
```

Two lines

```
set $(printf %x 65)
printf "\x$1"
```

Here is one if you do not mind using `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "%c", 65}'
```

Comment: Should work as well `printf "$(printf '\\x%02x' $char)"`

Answer (score 52):

This works (with the value in octal):

```
$ printf '%b' '\101'
A
```

even for (some: don't go over 7) sequences:

```
$ printf '%b' '\'{101..107}
ABCDEFG
```

A general construct that allows (decimal) values in any range is:

```
$ printf '%b' $(printf '\\%03o' {65..122})
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Or you could use the hex values of the characters:

```
$ printf '%b' $(printf '\\x%x' {65..122})
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

---

You also could get the character back with xxd (use hexadecimal values):

```
$ echo "41" | xxd -p -r
A
```

That is, one action is the reverse of the other:

```
$ printf "%x" "'A" | xxd -p -r
A
```

And also works with several hex values at once:

```
$ echo "41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a" | xxd -p -r
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

or sequences (printf is used here to get hex values):

```
$ printf '%x' {65..90} | xxd -r -p 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

---

Or even use awk:

```
$ echo 65 | awk '{printf("%c",$1)}'
A
```

even for sequences:

```
$ seq 65 90 | awk '{printf("%c",$1)}'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: The final example can even be extended to create a dynamically-generated ASCII table:

`seq 98 102 | awk 'BEGIN{print "\n\tDEC\tOCT\tHEX\tCharacter\n\t---\t---\t--\t-"}; {printf("\t%d\t%o\t%x\t%c\n",$1,$1,$1,$1)}; END{printf "\n"}'`


_{Thanks also to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226208/262439) to [a different question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226206/how-to-add-a-header-and-or-footer-to-a-sed-or-awk-stream)}_

Answer (score 20):

For your second question, it seems the leading-quote syntax (`\'A`) is specific to `printf`:

> If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote.

From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

Answer (score 13):

One option is to directly input the character you're interested in using hex or octal notation:

```
printf "\x41\n"
printf "\101\n"
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that works even if we don't have the % character on our keyboard :D
I was using a Linux terminal from postmarketOS on Nokia N900 and wanted to print it to copy-paste it in commands :)

Comment: I had to test whether a character was a CarriageReturn (`\r`) in a bash script and I found I had to use the following: `testchar=$'\r'; if [ ${testchar} = $'\r' ]; then echo "is true"; else echo "is false"; fi`. ASCII hex can be used in place of `\r`, ie. `$'\x0D'`. However, the string `"\r"`, or the hex equivalent, didn't work for the conditional, always returning false.

Comment: I can't find \x in the printf man page. Where is this documented? TIA

Answer (score 9):

For this kind of conversion, I use perl:

```
perl -e 'printf "%c\n", 65;'
```

Comment: or in perl, print chr(65), "\n";  While perl might be a good choice if you're doing a lot of this, using the shell's printf to convert your number into something that can go into a \0 escape sequence works just fine.  More complex with unicode, as you need \u support in your printf.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to save the ASCII value of the character:
(I did this in BASH and it worked)

```
{
char="A"

testing=$( printf "%d" "'${char}" )

echo $testing}
```

output:
65

Comment: This worked, thanks.  I wanted to get an Integer (ASCII code) from a typed character.  I made a script: {read -n 1 c;
echo $( printf "%d" "'${c}" )}

Answer (score 6):

If you convert `65` to hexadecimal it's `0x41`:

`$ echo -e "\x41"
A`

Comment: if you know the hex value to print ASCII character `$ printf "\x41"`

Answer (score 6):

For capital letters:

```
i=67
letters=({A..Z})
echo "${letters[$i-65]}"
```

Output:

```
C
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet another way to convert 65 into A (via octal):

```
help printf  # in Bash
man bash | less -Ip '^[[:blank:]]*printf'

printf "%d\n" '"A'
printf "%d\n" "'A"

printf '%b\n' "$(printf '\%03o' 65)"
```

To search in `man bash` for `\'` use (though futile in this case):

```
man bash | less -Ip "\\\'"  # press <n> to go through the matches
```

Comment: Thank you for the manpage parsing example!

Answer (score 2):

this prints all the "printable" characters of your basic bash setup:

```
printf '%b\n' $(printf '\\%03o' {30..127})

 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Comment: you're sure `\36 \37 and \177` are all that "printable" ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without *eval* nor *$()* nor `` :

```
ord () {
 local s
 printf -v s '\\%03o' $1
 printf "$s"
}

ord 65
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script prints `aaa...zzz` (i.e. `aaa > aab > aac > ... > zzx > zzy > zzz`)

```
for i in $(seq 0 25); do FIRST=$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $[97+$i]) | tr -d '\n'); for f in $(seq 0 25); do SECOND=$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $[97+$f]) | tr -d '\n'); for g in $(seq 0 25); do THIRD=$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $[97+$g]) | tr -d '\n'); echo "${FIRST}${SECOND}${THIRD}"; done; done; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that there are not that many 1-byte characters, but only 256, they can quickly be precomputed at your script startup:

```
declare -ag CHARS=()
for REPLY in {{0..9},{a..f}}{{0..9},{a..f}}; do
  printf -v CHARS[${#CHARS[@]}] "\x$REPLY"
done
```

(I reused the discardable `REPLY` variable, but you can `local` your own inside an init `function`)

Then...

```
$ echo "${CHARS[65]}"
A
$ i=65
$ echo "${CHARS[i]}"
A
```

Beware of `\x00`, whose value is not properly handled in Bash because it is the string terminator character:

```
$ var=$'qwe\x00rty'
$ echo ${#var}
3
$ echo "<${var}>"
<qwe>
```

So, `"${CHAR[0]}"` will always be a problem under Bash.

This way, you avoid output capture, inline text substitution and re-parsing once and again for every time you need to process one character; which is even worse for subprocess IPC through `xxd`, `awk` or `perl`.