# Generate random char in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I need to generate a huge text.

I'm using bash and I want to convert an integer number like `65` to a char like `A`.
So I use random value between `0` and `255` (I need all the ASCII table), convert to a char and redirect to a file using `>>`.
But I cannot make `bash` interpret the integer as a char.
Like `printf("%c", 65)` in C++.
But if I try this in bash, it returns 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer ASCII value to character in BASH using printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890262/integer-ascii-value-to-character-in-bash-using-printf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to chain it like

```
printf \\$(printf '%03o' $((65)))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to generate a huge random sequence of bytes, why not use [/dev/urandom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random)?

```
$ RANDOM=$( dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=1|base64 )
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1024 bytes (1.0 kB) copied, 0.00056872 s, 1.8 MB/s
$ echo $RANDOM
r553ONKlLkU3RvMp753OxHjGDd6LiL1qSdUWJqImggHlXiZjjUuGQvbSBfjqXxlM6sSwQh29y484
KDgg/6XP31Egqwo7GCBWxbEIfABPQyy48mciljUpQLycZIeFc/bRif0aXpc3tl5Jer/W45H7VAng
[...]
```

I piped the output to `base64` to avoid control characters that might confuse the terminal.

```
$ RANDOM=$( dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=1 )
```

or

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=outputfile bs=1024 count=1
```

will create a file with 1kB of random data.

Comment: The problem is i need between 1 - 255 (char code). The process need to compress it, even if it confuses the terminal. I just cannot get out the ascii table. Thanks

Comment: Then remove the `|base64` in my example above, and you will have a random sequence of bytes.

Comment: Bash doesn't handle binary data very well.

Comment: I'll not show it on the bash, i'll create a file and compress the data using my compressor, just to test if it's ok. It's a RLE compressor (in asm)

Comment: @demonofnight - compression doesn't work well on random data, it can even make the file bigger.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

[How do I convert an ASCII character to its decimal (or hexadecimal) value and back?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071)

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.