# increment a letter sequence to represent a whole number where a=0 and z=25

Tags: bash, sequence

I have tried several different search terms but have not found exactly what I want, I am sure there is already an answer for this so please point me to it if so.

I would like to understand how to increment a letter code given a standard number convention in a bash script.

Starting with `AAAA=0` or with leading zeros`AAAA=000000` (26x26x26x26) I would like to increment the value with a a positive single digit each time, so `aaab=000001`,`aaac=000002` and `aaba=000026` and `aaaca=000052` etc.

Thanks Art!

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890262/integer-ascii-value-to-character-in-bash-using-printf  converting a character to a number and back again. The rest is just math.

Comment: @JNevill no that seems to be a key code. I am after a value that is a UUID for an increasing sequence of numbers.

Comment: If you need to convert a number (an UUID) to a string of letters, please look at the conversion function in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fast

If you are aiming for speed and simplicity:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for text in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}; do
    printf '%06d %5.5s\n' "$i" "$text"
    (( i++ ))
done
```

#### Precise

Aiming at having a function that convert any number to the character string:

We must Understand that what you are describing is a number written in base 26, using the character `a` as `0`, `b` as `1`, `c` as `3`, etc.

Thus, `aaaa` means `0000`, `aaab` means `0001`, `aaac` means `0002`, .... `aaaz` means `0025`
and `aaba` means `0026`, `aaca` means `0052`.

bc could do the base conversion directly (as numbers):

```
$ echo 'obase=26; 199'|bc
07 17
```

The 7th letter is: a0, b1, c2, d3, e4, f5, g6, (h)7,
the 17th letter is (r).

If we set the variable list to:  `list=$(printf '%s' {a..z})` or `list=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

We could get each letter from the number with: `${list:7:1}` and `${list:17:1}`

```
$ echo "${list:7:1} and ${list:17:1}"
h and r
$ printf '%s' "${list:7:1}" "${list:17:1}"    # Using printf:
hr
```

---

#### Script

All together inside an script, is:

```
#!/bin/bash

list=$(printf '%s' {a..z})

getletters(){
    local numbers
    numbers="$(echo "obase=26; $1"|bc)"
    for number in $numbers; do
        printf '%s' "${list:10#$number:1}";
    done;
    echo;
}

count=2
limit=$(( 26**$count - 1 ))

for (( i=0; i<=$limit; i++)); do
    printf '%06d %-5.5s\n' "$i" "$(getletters "$i")"
done
```

Please change count from 2 to 4 to get the whole list. Be aware that such list is more than half a million lines: The limit is 456,975 and will take some time.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is what you want

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | tr ' ' '\n' | nl
```

will be too long, perhaps test with this first

```
 echo {a..z}{a..z} | tr ' ' '\n' | nl
```

if you don't need the line numbers remove last pipe and `nl`

If you need the output in xxxx=nnnnnn format, you can use awk

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '{printf "%s=%06d\n", $0, NR-1}'

aaaa=000000
aaab=000001
aaac=000002
aaad=000003
aaae=000004
aaaf=000005
aaag=000006
aaah=000007
aaai=000008
aaaj=000009
...
zzzv=456971
zzzw=456972
zzzx=456973
zzzy=456974
zzzz=456975
```

Answer (score 0):

With perl, you can `++` a string to increment the letter:

```perl
for (my ($n,$s) = (0,"aaaa"); $n < 200; $n++, $s++) {
    printf "%s=%0*d\n", $s, length($s), $n;
}
```

outputs

```
aaaa=0000
aaab=0001
aaac=0002
aaad=0003
...
aaby=0050
aabz=0051
aaca=0052
aacb=0053
...
aahp=0197
aahq=0198
aahr=0199
```