# Is there a way to implement a counter in bash but for letters instead of numbers?

Tags: bash

I'm working with an existing script which was written a bit messily. Setting up a loop with all of the spaghetti code could make a bigger headache than I want to deal with in the near term. Maybe when I have more time I can clean it up but for now, I'm just looking for a simple fix.

The script deals with virtual disks on a xen server. It reads `multipath` output and asks if particular LUNs should be formatted in any way based on specific criteria. However, rather than taking that disk path and inserting it, already formatted, into a configuration file, it simply presents every line in the format

```
'phy:/dev/mapper/UUID,xvd?,w',
```

UUID, of course, is an actual UUID.

The script actually presents each of the found LUNs in this format expecting the user to copy and paste them into the config file replacing each `?` with a letter in sequence. This is tedious at best.

There are several ways to increment a number in bash. Among others:

```
var=$((var+1))
((var+=1))
((var++))
```

Is there a way to do the same with characters which doesn't involve looping over the entire alphabet such that I could easily "increment" the disk assignment from `xvda` to `xvdb`, etc?

Comment: Would `for c in xvda xvdb ; do echo $c ; done` do? Or `for c in {a..c} ; do ...`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890262/integer-ascii-value-to-character-in-bash-using-printf

Answer (score 4):

To do an "increment" on a letter, define the function:

```
incr() {   LC_CTYPE=C printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$(($(printf '%d' "'$1")+1))")"; }
```

Now, observe:

```
$ echo $(incr a)
b
$ echo $(incr b)
c
$ echo $(incr c)
d
```

Because, this increments up through ASCII, `incr z` becomes `{`.

#### How it works

The first step is to convert a letter to its ASCII numeric value.  For example, `a` is 97:

```
$ printf '%d' "'a"
97
```

The next step is to increment that:

```
$ echo "$((97+1))"
98
```

Or:

```
$ echo "$(($(printf '%d' "'a")+1))"
98
```

The last step is convert the new incremented number back to a letter:

```
$ LC_CTYPE=C printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "98")"
b
```

Or:

```
$ LC_CTYPE=C printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$(($(printf '%d' "'a")+1))")"
b
```

## Alternative

With bash, we can define an associative array to hold the next character:

```
$ declare -A Incr; last=a; for next in {b..z}; do Incr[$last]=$next; last=$next; done; Incr[z]=a
```

Or, if you prefer code spread out over multiple lines:

```
declare -A Incr
last=a
for next in {b..z}
do
    Incr[$last]=$next
    last=$next
done
Incr[z]=a
```

With this array, characters can be incremented via:

```
$ echo "${Incr[a]}"
b
$ echo "${Incr[b]}"
c
$ echo "${Incr[c]}"
d
```

In this version, the increment of `z` loops back to `a`:

```
$ echo "${Incr[z]}"
a
```

Comment: I like that associative array method

Answer (score 2):

How about an array with entries A-Z assigned to indexes 1-26?

```
IFS=':' read -r -a alpharray <<< ":A:B:C:D:E:F:G:H:I:J:K:L:M:N:O:P:Q:R:S:T:U:V:W:X:Y:Z"
```

This has 1=A, 2=B, etc. If you want  0=A, 1=B, and so on, remove the first colon.

```
IFS=':' read -r -a alpharray <<< "A:B:C:D:E:F:G:H:I:J:K:L:M:N:O:P:Q:R:S:T:U:V:W:X:Y:Z"
```

Then later, where you actually need the letter;

```
var=$((var+1))
'phy:/dev/mapper/UUID,xvd${alpharray[$var]},w',
```

The only problem is that if you end up running past 26 letters, you'll start getting blanks returned from the array.

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines might be the simplest solution. I doubt we'll ever have to worry about >26 disks so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Bash 4 Range

You can use a Bash 4 feature that lets you specify a range within a [sequence expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). For example:

```
for letter in {a..z}; do
    echo "phy:/dev/mapper/UUID,xvd${letter},w"
done
```

See also [Ranges](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace#ranges) in the Bash Wiki.

Comment: The loop is specifically what I'm trying to avoid since it would require wrapping a mess of code. In the long run, I can worry about fixing the whole script to be more elegant making a loop a better option. For now I need to be able to say `var=a, var++` so to speak.

Comment: This is definitely available in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will return the next letter in the range a-z. An input of 'z' returns 'a'.

```
nextl(){
  ((num=(36#$(printf '%c' $1)-9) % 26+97));
  printf '%b\n' '\x'$(printf "%x" $num);
}
```

It treats the first letter of the input as a base 36 integer, subtracts 9, and returns the character whose ordinal number is 'a' plus that value mod 26.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Jot

While the Bash range option uses built-ins, you can also use a utility like the BSD *jot* utility. This is available on macOS by default, but your mileage may vary on Linux systems. For example, you'll need to install [athena-jot](https://packages.debian.org/sid/utils/athena-jot) on Debian.

#### More Loops

One trick here is to pre-populate a Bash array and then use an index variable to grab your desired output from the array. For example:

```
letters=( "" $(jot -w %c 26 a) )
for idx in 1 26; do
    echo ${letters[$idx]}
done
```

#### A Loop-Free Alternative

Note that you don't *have* to increment the counter in a loop. You can do it other ways, too. Consider the following, which will increment any letter passed to the function without having to prepopulate an array:

```
increment_var () {
    local new_var=$(jot -nw %c 2 "$1" | tail -1)
    if [[ "$new_var" == "{" ]]; then
        echo "Error: You can't increment past 'z'" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    echo -n "$new_var"
}

var="c"
var=$(increment_var "$var")
echo "$var"
```

This is probably closer to what the OP wants, but it certainly seems more complex and less elegant than the original loop [recommended elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355409/1301972). However, your mileage may vary, and it's good to have options!